# windows hibernate and problems with copying

Tags: dual-boot, hibernate

I hibernate windows 7 and open ubuntu.
 Afterthat, I mount my remaining drives(excluding C which I obviously can't) and use ubuntu .. but if I want to copy some file into other drives 
I can do it but when I restart ubuntu and resume windows I can't see them. To see those files in windows I have to restart windows.
Is there a way in which I can do this thing without actually restarting windows 7 'cause restarting windows takes hell lot of time

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When Windows is hibernated, it is just like the system is still up and running. When you boot Ubuntu and copy a file, Windows is unaware of the modifications you make on its back and still assumes that its NTFS partition hasn't changed since it was hibernated. In fact, everything you changed since then is considered as corruption and could cause serious problems in the filesystem structure, even running chkdsk could be a risk since it will try to make the filesystem consistent with Windows own view and will probably find that it differs.

NTFS-3g which is the tool that allows you to write to NTFS partitions should prevent you from mounting an hibernated partition as said in its manual:

> **remove_hiberfile**
>
> Unlike in case of read-only mount, the read-write mount is
>   denied if the NTFS volume is hibernated. One needs either to
>   resume Windows and shutdown it properly, or use this option which will
>   remove the Windows hibernation file. Please note, this means that the
>   saved Windows session will be completely lost. Use this option under
>   your own responsibility.

And also has an option for read-only in this case:

> **ro**
>
> Mount filesystem read-only. Useful if Windows is hibernated or
>   the NTFS journal file is unclean.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Good post! This is well formatted and includes plenty of details. The only thing I would suggest is adding links to outside sites or questions, so the user can do reading of their own! Good job!